# Razor Pages @functions block vs code block

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

In Razor Pages *cshtml* files, can someone tell me what is the difference between the following:

```
@functions
{
    // Etc.
}
```

And:

```
@{
    // Etc.
}
```

It almost seems like the same thing.

Comment: In the last.. can you add C# members (fields, properties, and methods) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the Official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

> @

Razor code blocks start with `@` and are enclosed by `{}`. Unlike expressions, C# code inside code blocks isn't rendered. Code blocks and expressions in a view share the same scope and are defined in order:

```
@{
    var quote = "The future depends on what you do today. - Mahatma Gandhi";
}

<p>@quote</p>

@{
    quote = "Hate cannot drive out hate, only love can do that. - Martin Luther King, Jr.";
}

<p>@quote</p>
```

> @code

The `@code` block enables a Razor component to add C# members (fields, properties, and methods) to a **component**:

```
@code{
    // C# members (fields, properties, and methods)
}
```

> @functions

The `@functions` directive enables adding C# members (fields, properties, and methods) to the **generated class**:

```
@functions {
    // C# members (fields, properties, and methods)
}
```

In Razor components, use `@code` over `@functions` to add C# members.

Comment: So, seems like they're pretty much the same thing then.

Comment: pretty much, since `@code` is an alias for `@functions`.  The clear distinction being `@code` and `@functions` can be used in `.razor` files, however `@code` is recommended over the latter.  For `cshtml` files, you can only use `@functions`. `@{ ...}` can be used in either, but unlike the previous are not for adding properties, methods or fields to the generated class.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question. By reading the [official documantation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-7.0), it states that:

*@functions methods serve as templating methods when they have markup:*

```
@{
   RenderName("Mahatma Gandhi");
   RenderName("Martin Luther King, Jr.");
}

@functions {
private void RenderName(string name)
{
    <p>Name: <strong>@name</strong></p>
}
```

The code renders the following HTML:

```
<p>Name: <strong>Mahatma Gandhi</strong></p>
<p>Name: <strong>Martin Luther King, Jr.</strong></p>
```

This leads me to understand that makes rendering html template easier.